# ASP.Net 4.0 Routing issue with path

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-routing

I am struggling with two issues regarding asp.net webform routing in 4.0 version.

**First issue** is with the path on local server same path works fine for other project & creates path issue in local server.

Second issue is routing doesn't work on actual hosting web server

Sample code

**Global.asx**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.gif(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

    // Page will Generate error if route for home page is take out then 
    // http://www.kashmirsouq.com without any page or quesry string wont work.

    routes.MapPageRoute(
         "HomeRoute",
         "",
         "~/Default.aspx"
     );


    ////For 
    routes.MapPageRoute("ParentCat", "buysell/{CatID}/{Title}", "~/buy-sell-in-kashmir.aspx", false,
         new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "CatID", "0" },
                    { "Title", "Product-Category-not-found" }},
         new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    { "CatID", "^[0-9a-fA-Z-]{36}$" }
                }); 
}
```

**ParentCategoryListing.ascx & .cs file code**

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptParentCategoryListing" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href='<%#getURLRouting(Eval("parentGUID"),Eval("CatName")) %>' title='<%#  Eval("CatLinkTitle")%>'>
                        <%#  Eval("CatName")%></a> </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>




protected string getURLRouting(object CatID, object CatTitle)
{
    string strTitle = CatTitle.ToString();

    #region Generate SEO Friendly URL based on Title
    //Trim Start and End Spaces.
    strTitle = strTitle.Trim();
    //Trim "-" Hyphen
    strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');
    strTitle = strTitle.ToLower();
    char[] chars = @"$%#@!*?;:~`+=()[]{}|\'<>,/^&"".".ToCharArray();

    //Replace . with - hyphen
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace(".", "-");
    //Replace Special-Characters
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        string strChar = chars.GetValue(i).ToString();
        if (strTitle.Contains(strChar))
        {
            strTitle = strTitle.Replace(strChar, string.Empty);
        }
    }
    //Replace all spaces with one "-" hyphen
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace(" ", "-");
    //Replace multiple "-" hyphen with single "-" hyphen.
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("-----", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("----", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("---", "-");
    strTitle = strTitle.Replace("--", "-");
    //Run the code again...
    //Trim Start and End Spaces.
    strTitle = strTitle.Trim();
    //Trim "-" Hyphen
    strTitle = strTitle.Trim('-');
    #endregion
    string url = null;
    try
    {
       // url = "~/news/" + NewsID + "/" + pageid + "/" + strTitle; // +"&pgName=" + PageName;
        url = "~/buysell/"+CatID + "/" + strTitle;
     //   return url;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Error");
    }
    return url;
}
```

**Partial Code from buy-sell-in-kashmir.aspx file**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["CatID"]))
    {
        sPID = RouteData.Values["CatID"].ToString();
        bIsGUID = IsGuid(sPID, out PID);
        addCanonicalURL = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sPID = Helper.GetQueryStringValue("CatID").ToString(); ;
        bIsGUID = IsGuid(sPID, out PID);
        addCanonicalURL = true;
    }


  // Code to get details based on sPID ParentCategory GUID
```

}

**Output**

with Current UserControl on default.aspx page generate following links for the Parent Categories

`http://localhost:59030/TravelKashir-Souq/~/buysell/1ef4f9db-14d1-4ff0-be79-922ce903bff4/electronics-technology`

in the above sample link it add `~/` when i use path as in user-control function `getURLRouting`

`url = "~/buysell/"+CatID + "/" + strTitle;`

and if i use path as

`url = "buysell/"+CatID + "/" + strTitle;` then link for Parent Category changes to

`http://localhost:59030/TravelKashir-Souq/buysell/1ef4f9db-14d1-4ff0-be79-922ce903bff4/electronics-technology`

on default.aspx page & routing works fine & when i click it goes to page **buy-sell-in-kashmir.aspx**

`http://localhost:59030/TravelKashir-Souq/buysell/1ef4f9db-14d1-4ff0-be79-922ce903bff4/buysell/1ef4f9db-14d1-4ff0-be79-922ce903bff4/electronics-technology`

on have tried different path still it doesnt work properly and when i upload the code on shared hosting it doesnt work & generates error

`HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

I am frustrated with this issue as i can make same path mentioned in the code works for other project without any issue.

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Website with our routing http://www.kashmirSouq.com & routing version which doesnt work http://demo2.kashmirsouq.com

Config: IIS 7.5/ asp.net 4.0 on both localhost & shared hosting

Comment: Probalby your <a> has to be an <asp:hyperlink> with runat=server

Comment: @Grumbler: That went unnoticed, that was the culprit for first issue let me see if it works on shared hosting

Comment: First issue resolved but i am still not able to run it on shared hosting i get the same error page not found

Comment: What is "shared hosting" in your case?

Comment: Hosting provide `MochaHost`

Comment: Have you tried to include the assemblies (Web.Routing) als local copy? I saw this helping in a similar case some times ago ...

Comment: Second Issue resolved i had to change asp.net pool to `asp.net 4.0 application pool`  as routing doesn't work in `classic pool`